# Does vcrpy's record_mode=None guarantee no HTTP requests will be sent even if the requests are made in a thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests, pytest, vcr

I am testing some code with pytest and using the vcrpy decorator as follows:

```
@pytest.mark.vcr(record_mode='none')
def test_something():
    make_requests_in_a_thread_and_save_to_queue()
    logged_responses = log_responses_from_queue_in_a_thread()
    assert logged_responses == expected_logged_responses
```

The test fails because the `logged_responses` are new responses, which are the results of new HTTP requests that have been made during `test_something()`.

I have a cassette saved in the correct place, but this is probably irrelevant because even if I didn't I should be getting a vcrpy CassetteError rather than a failed test.

Does record_mode='none' not apply to code executed within threads?

If not, how should I approach the testing problem? Thank you!

Comment: try it and find out?  what are you observing as the answer to your question and where are you stuck?

Comment: The tests fail as I mentioned, so the observation is that it does not apply to code executed within a thread. I am stuck because, if true, this is very inconvenient and I was hoping that someone might have looked into this before and found an appropriate resolution.
However, it is possible that I am just doing something wrong, and that it does work, in which case I would appreciate someone confirming that they have used record_mode=None successfully even when the requests are executed within a thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. I was using a stream API rather than sending http requests. `record_mode='none'` refers to http requests.